# How do I know if the drive in my notebook is an eDrive and thus uses bitlocker with no performance drop

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, windows-8.1, encryption

I have this [Toshiba](http://www.toshiba.co.il/en/laptops/portege/portege-z30-a/portege-z30-a-12q/) notebook and the specification only states the capacity of the SSD and says nothing about the type. It supports some hardware encryption via BIOS and via proprietary Toshiba software too. You can set a user password and an admin/master password. Not sure about the difference in this BIOS context. I presume it does not relate to Windows users since you can use different OS on the device.

How can I check if bitlocker is going to leverage the encryption mechanism built in the drive or not? Or better - how do I know if the drive supports it, because bitlocker will most likely leverage it, if it is possible.

Afterwards, I would like to do the same thing with [this drive](http://www.kingston.com/en/ssd/hyperx#sh103s3).  I heard there are issues with SandForce drives when talking about encryption. This drive does have a sandforce controller. Does it have the encryption mechanism built in? If not, is the next best thing to use bitlocker with the 10-20% performance drop?

Comment: It won't bitlocker does not use encryption hardware on the hdd only the tpm hardware on the motherboard

Comment: This source seems to say otherwise. http://www.anandtech.com/show/6891/hardware-accelerated-bitlocker-encryption-microsoft-windows-8-edrive-investigated-with-crucial-m500 Am I not understanding something correctly?

Comment: I tried it out, the encryption mechanism was slow. If it were to be using the ATA security mechanism, the encryption would be instant. But I can still use the encryption mechanism of the laptop drive itself, although there is no infromation about how it works and how secure it is. Can I find it out somehow? And what about the Kingston drive?